# onchange event for select tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery,where I am appending select tag inside a table for each row, I want to keep `onChange` event for each dropdown on every row. I tried using `onchange` event as shown, but not working. My jQuery code is as below:

```
for (var j = 0; j < leng; j++) {
    o = proplist[j];
    txt = "<tr><td>" + o.Value + "</td><td><select name=" + o.Key + "onchange='OnChange();'>";
    for (var k = 0; k < data.length; k++) {
        if (data[k] == o.Value || data[k] == o.Key) {
            txt1 += " <option selected>" + data[k] + "</option>";
        } else txt1 += " <option>" + data[k] + "</option>";
    }
    txt = txt + txt1 + "<option value='0'>Ignore</option></select></td></tr>";
    $("#propertycolumnListTable tbody").append(txt);
    txt = "";
    txt1 = "";
}
```

Comment: if you have a `OnChange()` function declared it SHOULD be called with this code, I would check if there are any errors showing in the firebug console.

Comment: Your `OnChange` function will need to be available on the global scope, so declare it outside of any other functions (like the jQuery DOM ready event handler).

Comment: And check you console, there are likely errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('select').change(function () {
    OnChange();
});
```

Comment: You can use $(parent).on('change', function () { OnChange() });

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function() {
  $("#propertycolumnListTable tbody").on("change","select",function() {
    // whatever you want when any select in the tbody changes
  });
});
```

and if you have jQuery, why not use it?

```
for (var j = 0; j < leng; j++) {
  o = proplist[j];
  var $tr = $("<tr/>");
  var $td = $("<td/>");
  var $sel = $("<select/>",{name:o.Key}); 
  $sel.append('<option value='0'>Ignore</option>');
  var selected = null;
  data.each(function() {
    $sel.append("<option/>",{value:this,text:this});  
    if (this == o.Value || this == o.Key) selected=this;
  });
  if (selected) $sel.val(selected);
  $td.append($sel);
  $tr.append($td);
  $("#propertycolumnListTable tbody").append($tr);
}
```